# Twig : Add JS file from included template

Tags: templates, include, twig, block, parent

I've got my main layout with a `{% block javascript %}`.
 A template is extending it. In this template, I've included my menu bar.. But in this menu bar, in some cases (depending of the parameters when I include it) it needs a special JS file.

But **I can't access a block from an included template** apparently. What can I do, instead of having to include it in every templates using this special menu bar ?

---

**EDIT :**

Here is some of my code.

*The layout :*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    {# ... #}
        {% block stylesheets %}
           {# ... #}
        {% endblock %}
    {# ... #}
    </head>
    <body id="bodyLayout">
        {# ... #}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}
        {# ... #}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

*One of the templates :*

```
{% extends "CDASvBundle:Default:layout.html.twig" %}
{# ... #}
<div class="col-sm-8">
  {% include 'CDASvBundle:Default:blocs-droite.html.twig' with {blocs : "lesPlusContrats"}  %}
</div>
```

*The `CDASvBundle:Default:blocs-droite.html.twig` template :*

```
{# ... #}
{% elseif blocs == 'Aide' %}
    <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rappel">› Rappelez-moi</a>
    {% include 'CDASvBundle:Component:rappelez-moi-popup.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

*And the `'CDASvBundle:Component:rappelez-moi-popup.html.twig` :*

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="rappel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
{# ... #}
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

To make it work it needs a special JS file, which contains some AJAX and other little things.

But I often ear it's not clean to write some JS in the middle of an HTML page, so I'd like to include this JS file at the end using the `javascripts` block from the main layout. Here is my problem !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to extend the parent block from the extending template like so:

```
{% block javascript %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {# Your other JavaScript files here #}
{% endblock %}
```

Give that a shot. Here's an example from the [docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#child-template).

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <style type="text/css">
        .important { color: #336699; }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p class="important">
        Welcome on my awesome homepage.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm not in the child template, the one extending the main layout, but I'm in the one which is included (using `{% include (...) %}`) by this child template (with your example, would be a 3rd template included in the second one).

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm not sure if this would work or not, but you could try having `{% block javascript %}{{ parent() }}{% endblock %}` in your second-level template, then extend that block in your third as in my answer above.

Comment: What do you mean by "then extend that block in your third" ? If you mean to extend my second-level template, I can't. The third one is included in many different second-level templates, though they are all extending the same main layout..

Comment: @Bonswouar - I'm not sure I completely follow the issue. I think the only way I'll be able to help is if you post the code.